# replace default label on xaxis

Tags: d3.js

I created a grouped bar chart using [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152) demo by the creator of d3 (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/juY5E/499/) for a working js fiddle). Along the xAxis, the chart displays numbered labels (0 - 19). These numbers seem to be used as the default, as the data sample (n) is an array of length 20 and there is no other explicit code that sets the label to equal the number.

Question: how can one set those labels to something else?

**code**

```
// create a range that is 20 
    var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(n))  //n = 20 [0,1,2,...19]
        .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

    var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(m))  // m = 4 , not relevant for this question
        .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

    var z = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x0) // xAxis is scaling the range of 20 along the bottom, there is no code setting the text of the label
        .orient("bottom");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike what the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44487966/5768908) proposes, you don't need two scales. You can do it all with just one scale:

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST".split("");

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(alphabet)
    .rangeBands([0, width], .2);
```

The catch is this: in the original code, since the domain was just an array of integers, Bostock was relying on the indices (`i`) to set the bars' x position.

The best alternative is creating a data array with the value (y position) and the letter (x position) for each data point. However, an easy alternative (doing minimal changes on the original code) is getting the letter by the index, like this:

```
.attr("x", function(d,i) { return x0(alphabet[i]); })
```

Here is the updated demo:

```js
var n = 20; // number of samples
var m = 4;

var data = d3.range(m).map(function() {
  return d3.range(n).map(Math.random);
});

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST".split("");

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(alphabet)
  .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(m))
  .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x1(i) + ",0)";
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("height", y)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x0(alphabet[i]);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - y(d);
  });
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to create two scales, using one for positioning and one for labels

```
 var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(n))  //n = 20 [0,1,2,...19]
        .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

 var alphabet = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(n))  //n = 20 ["a","b","c",..."t"]
        .rangeBands([0, width], .2);
```

Then, use one of them to create the xAxis, which, in this case, will put default labels "a", "b", "c"

```
this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(alphabet)
.orient("bottom");
```

When appending the `rect` use the other scale for positioning

```
 .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", y)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x0(i); }) //will set position according to x0 scale
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d); });
```

One would have to be careful that the two scales align properly in terms of length and positioning in the array i.e. if `n` is an array of 20 numbers, then the other array would have to have an array of 20 letters (as in this example).

I assume there is a better (less hacky) solution but this one works.